Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate stops at error "The given GUID does not exist in the term store"
My goal is to clone a whole site from one tenant to another.
I can obtain the content of the source site by opening a connection
Connect-PnPOnline -Interactive -ApplicationId…
and extracting the content
Get-PnPSiteTemplate…
I can open a connection to the target site, but when I try apply the template with
Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate -Path $templateFileName -ClearNavigation
I get an error saying "The given GUID does not exist in the term store".
Pointers to solution appreciation.

Are you using terms, managed metadata in your template? Can you check if they still exist in the termstore? Is it possible they were deleted?
The ID would still be referenced in the site, but no longer appliable.

Thank you for your answer. I am not sure whether I understand correctly. The source site made by somebody else, and they claim that they have not used any metadata terms. Yet, when I look at …/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx, there are some terms. In comparison the target site, which is just an out-of-the-box collaboration site), has none.

Do you see any reference to the terms in your PnP XML Template? Can you remove them?

I save the template into a PnP template file (template.pnp), which is essentially a ZIPped folder. If I now unzip this, I can find within the folder Files a file .xml that contains references to those terms. However, if I remove them and rezip the folder, I get the error "The Provisioning Template URI template.xml is not valid." when calling "Invoke". So something gets broken.

Ok, I think found the culpit. A couple of images had a keyword attached. I removed the keywords from those images, reextracted and reapplied and... bounced to an "unknown error". But hey, at least no more term store related errors.
